# Download compressed csv from github in R

Tags: r, github, curl

I must be missing something simple but I can't seem to create a call in R to pull this compressed csv from my github

Here's what I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(curl)

test <- read_csv(url('https://github.com/Jeffery-777/NBA-PBP-Scrape/blob/master/nba_pbp_96_97.csv.gz'))
```

It pulls one column of random content I'm not even sure what. Any help in creating the code to properly pull this data into the R environment would be appreciated.

Comment: If you paste that link into a browser, you'll see that it takes you to a *web page*, not a file. If you click on the "Download" button on that web page, you'll see that you get a redirection to the real file. And since `read_csv` deals with URLs natively, you don't need `url(...)`, so `read_csv("https://github.com/Jeffery-777/NBA-PBP-Scrape/raw/master/nba_pbp_96_97.csv.gz")`.

Comment: (If you read `?read_csv`, it says that *"Files starting with 'http://', 'https://', 'ftp://', or 'ftps://' will be automatically downloaded"*. No `url(...)` needed :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a feeling that was the issue but I'm not skilled enough to know where to look to figure it out. I see now you changed "blob" to "raw" and yes I just ran it and it works flawlessly! Many thanks @r2evans